# Movement Code Affected by Fps in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My current player movement code provides `0.32` translation on each key click.

If it is clicked 2 times very quickly, it should be `0.64`.

I provide this with coroutine, but it is affected by fps.

How do I ensure that it is not affected by fps?

I know `Time.deltaTime`, but how do I get exactly `0.32` if I multiply by `Time.deltaTime`?

My current move code:

```
public float move = 0.32f; //movement limitation
public float repeat = 4;  // I perform 0.32 in 4 parts to be more smooth.
 
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) //Exapmle key. I have 4 ways to move
    {
        StartCoroutine("Left");
    }
}
 
IEnumerator Left()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= repeat; i++)// as I said, I perform 0.32 in 4 parts to be more smooth.
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(-move / repeat, 0, 0);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always scale your movement with your frame-time. See [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html). You need to define a movement speed by second instead of movement per click.

Comment: @JonasH didn't OP already mention that but asked **how** to do it exactly? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to be smooth rather use a fixed speed and do e.g.

```
// distance to move
public float move = 0.32f;
// speed in Unity units per second
public float speed = 1f;
 
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) 
    {
        StartCoroutine(Left);
    }
}
 
IEnumerator Left()
{
    // Pre-calculate the target position
    // This is the huge advantage of IEnumerators -> you can store local variables over multiple frames
    var targetPosition = transform.position + Vector3.left * move;

    // track how far you have already moved
    var moved = 0f;
    // Loop until you moved enough
    while(moved < move)
    {
        // the step is now frame-rate independent and moves the object with a fixed value per second
        var step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        // every frame move one such step towards the target without overshooting
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, step);
        // keep track of the movement
        moved += step;

        yield return null;
    }

    // and to end up with a clean value in the end
    transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

---

However

> If it is clicked 2 times very quickly, it should be 0.64

this wouldn't be covered. In order to do this I would actually use a completely different approach without Coroutines at all and rather simply use e.g.

```
// distance to move
public float move = 0.32f;
// speed in Unity units per second
public float speed = 1f;
 
Vector3 targetPosition;

void Start()
{
    targetPosition = transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow) 
    {
        targetPosition += Vector3.left;
    }

    ...

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

so now you can smash your move keys in any direction as much as you like and it will simply sum them all up into the one `targetPosition` and always keep moving towards it smoothly but with a fixed velocity.

or another alternative would be to interpolate and rather make the object move faster if it is further away from the target but slower the closer it comes

```
// 5 here is an arbitrary number based on experience -> tweak it according to your needs
public float interpolation = 5f;

...

transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, interpolation * Time.deltaTime);
```